# simple condition on wordpress function.php not work

Tags: php, function, wordpress, hook

i want add a new field "title" on comment of wordpress, after insert the new input field in a default form of wordpress i added this in my `function.php` for save the title when new comment are submitted.

this is the code i use for save title:

```
function add_comment_meta_values($idcommento) {

global $post;
$idcommento= get_comment_ID();
$tipodipost= get_post_type($post->ID);

            if( get_post_type($post->ID) == 'service') {



            if(isset($_POST['title_svz']) ) {
        $title= wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['title_svz']);
        add_comment_meta( $idcommento , 'title_svz', $title, false);
            }}

}

add_action ('comment_post', 'add_comment_meta_values', 1);
```

this code work only when remove the condition   :

```
      if( get_post_type($post->ID) == 'service') {}
```

and i don't understand why, i have already tried this condition in comment.php or in a footer with simple function like this

```
function test_function() {

            if( get_post_type($post->ID) == 'service') { echo 'done'; }


}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'test_function' );
```

and it's work, so i don't understand why don't work in my primary code, any idea ?

**SOLVED MYSELF**

THIS IS THE NEW CODE:

```
function add_comment_meta_values($idcomment) {

$comment_full = get_comment( $idcomment ); 
$idpost = $comment_full->comment_post_ID;
$typepost= get_post_type($idpost); 


    if( $typepost == 'service') {

            if(isset($_POST['title_svz']) ) {
        $title= wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['title_svz']);
        add_comment_meta( $idcomment , 'title_svz', $title, false);
            }    } 

}

add_action ('comment_post', 'add_comment_meta_values', 10, 1);
```

Comment: if( $post->post_type == 'service')

Comment: tried , but the result are the same , not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in Wordpress, depending on the Context, the global $post may give you unexpected result. Thus something like $post->ID may not point to the appropriate ID you are looking for. You may as well try inspecting the $post object to see if it is what you had expected; like so:

```
        <?php

            function add_comment_meta_values($idcommento) {        
                global $post;
                // TRY DUMPING THE $post VARIABLE TO SEE WHAT YOU GET
                var_dump($post->ID);
                var_dump($post->post_type);
                var_dump($post);
                exit;

                $idcommento = get_comment_ID();
                $tipodipost = get_post_type($post->ID);

                // ALTHOUGH THIS IS ESSENTIALLY THE SAME AS WHAT YOU DID
                if( $post->post_type == 'service') {

                    if(isset($_POST['title_svz']) ) {
                        $title= wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['title_svz']);
                        add_comment_meta( $idcommento , 'title_svz', $title, false);
                    }}

            }

            add_action ('comment_post', 'add_comment_meta_values', 1);
```

After the Inspection, you'd sure know where and what was not OK in your Code...

Comment: how i can see the var_dump on the specific position  of function ?

Comment: ok i have submitted the comment and the result with var_dump is this "NULL NULL NULL", so for every variable receive a null, why ?