# save comment meta with conditional functions

Tags: wordpress, comments

I have created an elearning environment where authors can manually add questions to each post. The questions are added to the regular wordpress comment form.

Everything works well, except saving the user input.

First step is: I want to retrieve the questions from the post and then use each of them to save the input.

So far i have the following.

```
//Save fields
function save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
    $level = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'level',true);
    if (is_singular('programma') && $level == 'les' ){
        $questions = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'vragen',true);
        foreach ($questions as $name=>$type){
            $nametwee = str_replace(" ","_",$name);
            $input = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST[$nametwee]);
            add_comment_meta( $comment_id, $nametwee, $input );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_meta_data' );
```

add_comment_meta seems to be not working in combination with get_post_meta function.

I tried to change the priority (lower(99) and higher(01)) but that doesnt solve it.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, thanks to this post: [simple condition on wordpress function.php not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511786/simple-condition-on-wordpress-function-php-not-work)

Solution is not to use function is_singular('programma') and get_the_id().

Instead, use the comment_id to retrieve the post_id and then the post type.

So updated, tested and it works now:

```
//Save fields
function save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
    $comment_full = get_comment( $comment_id ); 
    $idpost = $comment_full->comment_post_ID;
    $typepost= get_post_type($idpost); 
    $level = get_post_meta($idpost,'level',true);
    if ($typepost=='programma' && $level == 'les' ){
        $questions = get_post_meta($idpost,'vragen',true);
        foreach ($questions as $name=>$type){
            $nametwee = str_replace(" ","_",$name);
            $input = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST[$nametwee]);
            add_comment_meta( $comment_id, $nametwee, $input );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_meta_data' );
```